# Unauthorized 401 error in laravel 6 passport

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, laravel-passport

I'm trying to use the laravel passport to authenticate users. I followed every step in laravel passport documentation. But it shows error when I access a route that is protected by 'auth:api' middleware. I've searched over the internet but any of the answers are not working so far. Please see the code, and what I've tried so far below.

**Tech used**

- Laravel 6
- Laravel Passport
- Vue 2
- Axios

**Tried so far:**

- Changed `Passport::routes();` to `Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/oauth', 'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'web', 'auth']]);` in `AuthServiceProvider`. Also tried `Passport::routes(null, ['prefix' => 'api/oauth');`
- Tried to run `php artisan cache:clear`

**routes/api.php**

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    Route::get('user', function() {
        return request()->user();
    });

    Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index')->name('posts');
    Route::post('posts/store', 'PostController@store')->name('posts.store');
    Route::get('posts/{id}/show')->name('posts.show');

    Route::get('users/{id}/show')->name('users.show');
});
```

**Axios**

```
mounted() {
   axios.get('/api/posts')
      .then(res => this.posts = res.data).catch(error => console.log('Unable to fetch posts.'))
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Headers:

[image]

Please let me know if you need some details that is not indicated on my post yet.

**Setup**

1. Run `composer require laravel/passport:9` for the installation.
2. Run `php artisan migrate` for the tables.
3. Run `php artisan passport:install` to generate the encryption keys.
4. Added `Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens` trait in `User` model.
5. Added `Passport::routes();` in `AuthServiceProvider`.
6. Changed `guard`'s `api` driver to `passport` in `config/auth.php`.

**Full source code:**

[Click this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IIMzElNpMjkXUc21JbNsKGbDFQAwyiUA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please to give more details, how you setup the laravel passport?

Comment: @Dmitry Please check my update on my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should review your code with the following steps.

**Step 1**: `User` model has to use HasApiTokens

```
...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
}
```

**Step 2**: `Passport::routes` method within the boot method of your `AuthServiceProvider`

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
...
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
    }
}
```

**Step 3**: In your `config/auth.php` configuration file, you should set the driver option of the api authentication guard to passport

```
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

**Step 4** (Optional):
If you want to consume your API from your JavaScript application, you need to manually send an access token to the application and pass it with each request to your application. However, `Passport` includes a middleware that can handle this for you. All you need to do is add the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware to your web middleware group in your `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```
'web' => [
    // Other middleware...
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
],
```

! You should ensure that the `CreateFreshApiToken` middleware is the last middleware listed in your middleware stack.

**Edit** (2021/10/17):
You should try to add the auth middleware to `$middlewareGroups` of your `Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
...
  'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'auth:api', //Need to add
  ],
];
```

**Edit** (2021/10/25):
I downloaded your code and debug it. When you debug it, you will get the following result:

[image]

Header JWT is not valid for JSON structure. There seems to be an incompatibility between the `Laravel Passport` library and your system. You should check your system version (PHP, Laravel, etc). I will continue to investigate. If you have any new information, please let me know

**Edit** (2021/11/02):

> Update your laravel/framework dependency to ^6.0 in your composer.json file. If installed, update your laravel/passport dependency to ^9.3.2 in your composer.json file.

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#updating-dependencies

According to Laravel `6.x` documentation, the version of Laravel Passport is from 9.3.2. Please try this version.

Comment: This is exactly my setup. But it is weird that I am still getting the `Unauthenticated (401)` error. I've also tried to upgrade the passport to version `9.*` but still getting the same error.

Comment: Im still getting the same error.

Comment: @Jie You try to upgrade to Passport v9.3.2. Tell me if you have any problems.

Comment: Seriously!? Changing the passport version works! Any idea why? Please edit your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  Api/oauth prefix AND add the auth:api middleware than you need to authenticate via Bearer tokens.

So it may be you have csrf token related issue so try below to disable it.

```
Passport::ignoreCsrfToken(true);
```

Comment: Im still getting the same error. I've added that code inside the `AuthServiceProvider` after the `Passport::routes();`

Comment: I think you have missed some steps of passport installation. Please check all steps of https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport 

 you should call the Passport::routes method within the boot method of your App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider. This method will register the routes necessary to issue access tokens and revoke access tokens, clients, and personal access tokens:

Answer (score 0):

You should add token bearer into your ajax requests. You can get it after successful login.

```
// laravel
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;

public function login()
{
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();

    if (!$user || !$token = Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['success'=> false, 'error' => 'неверный логин или пароль', 'cr' => $credentials], 422);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

---

```
// vue login
async function login(email, password) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/auth/login', {email, password});
    
    const token = response.data.token;
    
    // some func to store token, I am using vuex mutations for this
    storeToken(token);
  }
  catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

// vue regular function
async function changePassword(newPassword) {
  // get token from global storage, with vuex it will be like store.state.auth.token
  const token = getToken();

  await axios.post('/user/changePassword', {newPassword}, headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've forgotten to run [`php artisan passport:keys`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#deploying-passport) ...so there may be no RSA key-pair available, which is crucial. Clients usually can be added with: `php artisan passport:client`. And generally speaking, there is no default recipe for debugging Laravel middleware ...there only is [`xdebug`](https://xdebug.org/docs/install#pecl).

Comment: I believe that `php artisan passport:keys` is only when you deploy it on the production server. This is based on the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#deploying-passport